# How to print out unique random numbers from array without repeating

Tags: java, arrays

I need to simply print numbers with 0-9 from array in order `without duplicating the numbers`  in a random order

> Example: 0367458192

So far, I have this but It prints out the numbers with `spaces`,`,` and `[` which I don't want. I feel like this is really simple but I just cant figure it out. Thanks

```
    package garbage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;


public class ReversalGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    }
}
```

Comment: One solution could be: 

`System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining()));`. Which Java version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of `Arrays.toString` and then use `String::replaceAll` to get rid of what you do not want

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[10];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(arr));
String res = Arrays.toString(arr).replaceAll("\\[|\\]|,|\\s", "");
System.out.println(res);
```

**output**

```
3752486019
```

Comment: Now if i were to have to reorganize those numbers, like the question is to make a game that prints out numbers 0-9 in a random order, then have the user input a number (n), then from 0 to n, all those numbers reverse order, should I have made this a string instead to use like charAt

Comment: I suggest that you get into the habit of viewing javadocs.  If you look at `String` you will see that there is `charAt` also `toCharArray()` and also you could just use a foreeach loop.